# Why button image does not change when it pressed in Android?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button, android-selector

I am new to android and I created Simple application. When click button textview should change that function work fine but button image does not change while it pressed.

here my button in **fragment_main.xml**

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/plus"
        android:onClick="changeText" />
```

Here the code of **custom.xml** file in **drawable folder**. (**There was not a default drawable folder and I creted it**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/plus_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/plus_highlighted" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/plus"/>

</selector>
```

**plus_selected.png,plus_highlighted.png and plus.png** files are in **drawable-hdpi** folder

Here my java code

```
public void changeText(View v) {

    TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    tvText.setText("you cliked the button");

}
```

When click button textview changed into "You clicked the button" but **plus.png** images is always exist as button image. it does not change while pressing

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change

```
android:background="@drawable/plus"
```

to

```
android:background="@drawable/custom"
```

set background as `selector`. `custom.xml` is selector in your case.